# Fetch text from anchr tag using regex and convert to hyperlink in java

Tags: java, html, regex, hyperlink

I am trying to extract text from a tag in html and convert that text into a hyperlink.Below is the code I have written

```
String test = "<a href=\"https://jira.com/browse/\"></a>"+myVariableTicketNumber;
String regex = "<a href=(\"[^\"]*\")[^<]*</a>";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
String s = m.replaceAll("$1");
```

The output is https://jira.com/browse/myVariableTicketNumber which is a hyperlink.So when I click on it,it redirects me to a concerned page.

**Required Output**
I want only my ticket number as output and it should be hyperlink i.e when I click on myVariableTicketNumber it should redirect me to concerned page

So even if I fetch the myVariableTicketNumber will it be a hyperlink?If not what should be done to make it a hyperlink rather than appending https://jira.com/browse to it

Comment: you're asking "how can I make a hyperlink without it being a hyperlink"

Comment: Hi @Chase hope you got my question.Is there any way that can be done?For example if myVariableTicketNumber is abc-1234 then my hyperlink will be https://jira.com/browse/abc-1234 which when click redirect me to concerned page.But I want it to be only abc-1234 which when clicked should redirect to concerned page

Comment: you cannot just make the *actual hyperlink* not a hyperlink, have you considered changing the *text* of the `a` tag to your ticket number but keeping the `href` same?

Comment: can you provide me with an example or a working scenario?